# Propositional Identities which are both equal to XOR

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm doing some textbook problems involving discrete mathematics, specifically sets and their **symmetric difference**. Now, I think that all problems involving sets can be translated into logical operations, that's probably how sets were discovered/invented in the first place.

Anyway, the problem. We have this:
$$\alpha:a \oplus b = (a \lor b) \land \neg(a \land b)$$ 
And we have this:
$$\beta:a \oplus b = (a \land \neg b) \lor (b \land \neg a)$$

I tried multiple times already to show that the right sides are logically equivalent, but failed.

So, basically can somebody show me **step by step** how to get from one side to the other in the following equation? 
 $$(a \lor b) \land \neg(a \land b) = (a \land \neg b) \lor (b \land \neg a)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a \lor b) \land \neg(a \land b) =$ (DeMorgan)

$(a \lor b) \land (\neg a \lor \neg b) =$ (Distribution) (like FOIL)

$(a \land \neg a) \lor (a \land \neg b) \lor (b \land \neg a) \lor (b \land \neg b)=$ (Complement)

$\bot \lor (a \land \neg b) \lor (b \land \neg a) \lor \bot=$ (Identity) ($\bot$ is identity element for $\lor$, just as 0 is for +)

$(a \land \neg b) \lor (b \land \neg a)$

Comment: Oh my .. this is simple..I guess I'm too tired. Anyway, thanks! I will accept your answer when the system allows me to. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!